# Slow or unresponsive VBA excel macro for copying of data from word to outlook body to be sent out via loop

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, ms-word

I am working on a excel vba macro to send out 5000+ emails to different email addresses.

The logic is, macro will open the word document, copy the data, close word doc, paste it on outlook body then send.

It is working with the codes below but the problem is the macro is so slow and sometimes unresponsive after 10 to 15 emails on the loop.

I will surely appreciate all the suggestion and help regarding this matter. Thank you so much in advance!

```
Sub EmailBlast()

If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to send emails?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

Dim objOL As New Outlook.Application
Dim objMail As MailItem
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim wd As Object, editor As Object
Dim doc As Object
Dim irow As Integer
irow = 11

On error Goto err1

Do
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
Set objOL = New Outlook.Application
Set objMail = objOL.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set doc = wd.Documents.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\word document.docx")
doc.Content.Copy
doc.Close
Set wd = Nothing
Set editor = objMail.GetInspector.WordEditor

With objMail
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = "xxxxx@email.com" 
    .To = Cells(irow, 1).Value
    .Subject = "Important News: Subject matter"
    .BodyFormat = olFormatRichText
    editor.Content.Paste
    .Display

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.SendKeys "%s"
End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set objMail = Nothing
Set objOL = Nothing
Cells(irow, 2).Value = "Sent"

err1:
irow = irow + 1

Loop Until Cells(irow, 1).Value = ""

MsgBox "Email sent!"

End Sub
```

Regards,
Meiji

Comment: First of all you create a new outlook application every iteration in the loop `Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")`. Don't do that. Instead create it only once **before** the loop and re-use the same Outlook in the loop and destroy it **after** the loop ended `Set objOL = Nothing`. Same for your Word application `Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")`. Give that a try and check out, this should improve speed already a lot. • For further investigation we should know: How many rows do you have? How many emails will be generated?

Comment: Thanks! I've tried it and it significantly improve the speed. 6273 rows to be exact.

Comment: I've tried both codes for 40 emails, 6mins on the posted codes here and 3 mins for your suggestion. Thanks! but can we still improve the speed?

Comment: Well, 6273 will take some time: If every mail takes only 0.5 second to be created and sent, that means 52 minutes in total. I guess there is not much to improve speed further. Note that you still open a word document for each email. This alone will take time that you cannot improve (if it isn't the same document everytime).

Comment: Is the content of the email the same everytime or does it change? • Also note that you don't need to `.Display` the mail. Just send it directly with `.Send` instead of using `Application.SendKeys "%s"`.

Comment: It is same document every time, I remove the closing of word doc on the loop so it can just copy the word document and close after the loop.  Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: If it is exactly the same E-Mail you can send only one E-Mail with all recepients in the `.BCC` see [MailItem.BCC property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.bcc). This way you will only have to generate one email that will be sent to everyone and no one can see the others email addresses. • So genenerate one email before the loop. Fill in all the .bcc recipients inside the loop. Finally send the email after the loop. Should be done within seconds then. as `.To =` you can set your own email-address (this is what everyone sees).

Comment: Unfortunately, if I do not display the mail It will just send blank email. I am happy now with the result. Thank you so much!

Comment: What if the click on the reply all button? Would it be a problem if I include them all in the BCC?

Comment: No, the only email address they will see is the one in `.To =` where you put your own (you will get one copy too). If they press reply all the will reply only to `.To =`. All the addresses you put into `.BCC` are safely hidden (the "B" stands for blind). Actually with this technique the email server will multiply the email and send one copy to everyone in the `.BCC`. So the server does all the work of generating `6273` copies out of one (and that is much faster than letting outlook do the work).

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know that. few more questions, if the email address has an automatic reply, or not an active email, would I be able to receive notification for that? Also, Can I just send all 6273 recipients in one email?

Comment: Actuall what you should check if there is a limitation on the amount of addresses you can add to `.BCC` (or if you mail server limits it). I don't know that. If there is no limit you can send all 6273 mails at once. Anyway you will receive notifications form any address that answers or fails to deliver.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate your help! :)